# Converting VB.net lambda expression anonymous type result to known type

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda, anonymous-types

I don't have much VB.net experience and I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm doing wrong.  I have a lambda expression that returns a result set of anonymous type.  I'm trying to convert this set to a known type and return it back to the calling method but I can't get the result set to convert to a known type.  Or, maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.  Error is "cannot convert anonymous type to QuickSearchViewModelDataObject type".  Any help will be appreciated.

Class:

```
Public Class QuickSearchViewModelDataObject
    Public Property ItemNum As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property OnHandQty As Integer?
    Public Property PriceClass As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal?
    Public Property TakeOrderF As Boolean
    Public Property Warranty As String
    Public Property ActiveF As Boolean
End Class
```

Method:

```
Public Function GetItemByItemNumber(itemNumber As String) As QuickSearchViewModelDataObject Implements Model.IInventoryRepository.GetItemByItemNumber

    Using context As New MBAModel
        Dim returnedItem = context.OneInventories.Join(context.TwoInventories,
                                         Function(mi) mi.ItemNum,
                                         Function(im) im.ItemNum,
                                         Function(mi, im) New With {mi, im}) _
                                   .Select(Function(o) New With
                                   {
                                        .Description = o.mi.Description, _
                                        .OnHandQty = o.im.OnHandQty, _
                                        .PriceClass = o.mi.Class, _
                                        .Warranty = o.mi.Warranty, _
                                        .Price = o.im.Price, _
                                        .TakeOrderF = o.mi.TakeOrderF, _
                                        .ItemNum = o.mi.ItemNum, _
                                        .ActiveF = o.mi.ActiveF
                                    }).Where(Function(x) x.ItemNum = itemNumber AndAlso x.ActiveF).FirstOrDefault()

            Return returnedItem
    End Using

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** OneFineDay is right - you can get a `QuickSearchViewModelDataObject` right from your Join; no need for a Select. On the third argument of the Join:

```
Function(mi, im) New QuickSearchViewModelDataObject() With {
    .Description = mi.Description, _
    ...
})
...
```

That's all you need to get the correct object type at the end.
See fiddle: [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S3LD6A)

I'll leave my earlier answer up in case it helps someone else:

If you are dealing with `IEnumerable(Of QuickSearchViewModelDataObject)` the whole time, you don't need to project it with Select. But if you're dealing with an anonymous type (from an earlier `Join`, for example), and you need to project to your final desired type, it's easy:

```
.Select(Function(o) New QuickSearchViewModelDataObject() With {
    .Description = o.mi.Description, _
    .OnHandQty = o.im.OnHandQty, _
    .PriceClass = o.mi.Class, _
    .Warranty = o.mi.Warranty, _
    .Price = o.im.Price, _
    .TakeOrderF = o.mi.TakeOrderF, _
    .ItemNum = o.mi.ItemNum, _
    .ActiveF = o.mi.ActiveF
})
```

In this case, it doesn't matter what shape the LINQ query takes before the Select - you're definitely going to get a `QuickSearchViewModelDataObject` out of it. (This is also useful if you want to project to a DTO and not your entity object).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the Select clause, just the Where clause and this will return the Entity Type.

```
      .Where(Function(x) x.ItemNum = itemNumber AndAlso x.ActiveF).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Isn't the result of the `Join` an anonymous type - `New With {mi, im}`?

Comment: That should be removed as well.

Comment: Good point. I haven't done LINQ Joins in a while, especially in VB.NET. Cheers.